# Why can't I connect to internet using WiFi?

Tags: wireless, networking, internet

I'm using HP Compaq NX9600. I installed Ubuntu last night and I only can connect to Internet by a wired connection. It doesn't let me choose a WiFi connection.

How do I resolve the issue?

Comment: You might need to install wireless drivers, do you ?

Comment: while connected via lan please go to 'settings' -> ' additional drivers' and see if any wifi drivers are suggested.

Comment: Does it recognize your Wi-Fi adapter at all?